mpl FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import (inset_axes,InsetPosition,mark_inset)

when I run the code, the following error happens
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified. 'c:\\Program\\circumstance\\Python3.9\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib.libs.'

In fact, when I first run the code, there is no error.
To solve the problem, I checked my Python file folder. It already has the mpl_toolkits folder.
So I tried to pip uninstall matplotlib and mpl_toolkits and pip install them again. Unluckily, it makes nothing.

Have you checked out similar questions like this one? Also, it could be of help if you isolate only the import(s) that actually cause the issue. Does it still happen if you comment out the import mpl_toolkits line? And the import matplotlib.pyplot?
